# How to view child in angular2 and what it is for?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

Recently I have been using jqgrid for angular2 while following their document.

I found the code, [HERE](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/angular2/index.htm#demos/angular2/angular-grid-editing.htm) and copied from there but in my file I have come across a type error like in the screenshot and I am not sure about that. Can anyone suggest how to suppress it please. Thanks.

> ts
>   Experimental suppport for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release.
>   Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Comment: Hi Gunter,from your answer i understood that view child is used to get the  local variable of a template to component?

Comment: @ViewChild('buttonReference') myButton: jqxButtonComponent;

Comment: Or to an element with a specific template variable or to a component or directive without a template variable (searching by type instead of string).

Comment: What i am doing from my step,i am sending the button referance to jqxbuttonComponent?

Comment: Pls see my latest screen shot it got error in ts and not allowing to use view chid.

Comment: This searches for an element in the view of the component that has a `#buttonReference` template variable and returns the `jqxButtonComponent` component instance. The value is available when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called

Comment: That's not Angular related. That's related to your IDE. I don't know about that.

Comment: Try to add `"experimentalDecorators": true` in your tsconfig.json